# Is there a way in netlogo to get a turle to leave the simulation area and then come back after a certain number of ticks?

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a evacuation simulation, my turtles represent vehicles that leave an area, I currently do this by having the turtle die when it reaches the evacuation point, however I would like to have the vehicle return show up elsewhere on the map and return to the original point of origin (to pick up more passengers to evacuate) I am unsure hide turtle will do this properly, because I don't want the turtle interacted with while it is "off the map" Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Jon,

Two ways I can think of.

One would be to indeed make the vehicle hidden and then have all your normal interactions with turtles be instead with `vehicles with [not hidden?]`.  You could then refer to the hidden vehicles as `vehicles with [hidden?]`.  I'm assuming that you have a `vehicles` breed, but if all turtles are vehicles, then it would be `turtles with [not hidden?]`, etc.

But breeds suggests a different approach.  Turtles can change their breeds, so if you have a breed `vehicles`, then you could create another breed (say) `inactive-vehicles`.  When a vehicle has reached the evacuation point, you could ask it to `set breed inactive-vehicle` and `set hidden? true`.  You could then continue to refer to active cars as `vehicles` and these inactive cars as `inactive-vehicles`.  So, `ask vehicles ...` will just refer to those that are still active. You could then ask `inactive-vehicles` to go wherever you wish and then reset their breed to `vehicles`.  (I'm not sure `inactive-vehicles` is great breed name, but it can be anything you want.)

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: Yes thanks I think this will work with what I want to do